# Set up impersonation with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

for a first understanding, I have created a very simple project which tries to count the number of files in two directories. `User1` is not allowed to access `Directory2` and `User2` is not allowed to access `Directory1`. Due to impersonation I should get only one number, depending on the user who is calling my application. Both user are set up as administrators.

So I have created a new MVC-project in Visual Studio 2015 (running on Windows 8.1) and selected to use Windows authentication. Once the application is up and running (in ISS Express), I switch to `User1` on my machine (there is no Active Directory) and call the website in Internet Explorer (yes, "Integrated Windows authentication" is enabled in the settings). With this setup, the user in `HttpContext.User.Identity` is `User1` and `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` is my development user, the one I am working with in Visual Studio.

I have also tried to impersonate manually:

```
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)User.Identity;
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{
    ctx = winId.Impersonate();

    // GetNumbers() tries to get the number of files for both directories       
    numbers = GetNumbers();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
finally
{
    if (ctx != null)
    {
        ctx.Undo();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the exception "Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid." Some people were claiming the this one solved their problem: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB56194 Not for me. I've added `User1` and my own user to the lists and restarted the computer. No change.

The only thing which gives me a little bit of hope is the impersonation with a separate login, as described on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx#paght000023_impersonatingusinglogonuser The disadvantages are quite obvious: I have to have the user's password and why should I login again if the user already did it for me.

Although this is a new project without major changes by me, some more information just for sanity check...

My `Web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

My project settings are

- "Anonymous authentication" is `false`
- "Windows authentication" is `true`
- "Managed pipline mode" is `Integrated`

Any suggestions on what to change to make this simple project work as expected?

Best regards,
   Carsten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work (IIS Express and IIS)! As mentioned above, the first approach was a prototype only. The final goal was to create a GUI which runs on server A and an API which runs on server B. Both implemented with ASP.NET.

The `Web.config` of the GUI and the API got these settings:

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>
```

The project property (press `F4` after selecting the project) "Managed pipline mode" is set to `Classic`.

Somewhere on SO I saw a discussion about if the impersonation should work with `HttpClient` as well. It was said, it does. Well, it did not for me. And the `WebClient` is no fun if you are using a variety of HTTP methods. So I switched to RestSharp:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
```

- Special note for Visual Studio: You have to start Visual Studio as administrator or else the impersonation will not work on IIS Express!
- Special note for IIS: The application pool has to use `Classic` "Managed pipeline mode".
- Special note (while testing): At first, the API asked me to authenticate, which it should not. The reason was quite simple: My user `user1` on my development machine had another password then the `user1` on my target machine...

I hope this helps someone.